# Error al instalar Odoo desde el código fuente en Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

Es mi primera pregunta y soy bastante nuevo en esto, por eso mis disculpas de antemano.
Estoy instalando Odoo desde el código fuente (no con el instalador) en Windows10. Ya tengo todo configurado, pero al ejecutarlo y crear la base de datos me aparece el siguiente error.

[image: Error al crear la base de datos que se ve en el navegador]

Ahora bien, al dirigirme a la consola desde donde lo he ejecutado me aparecen los siguientes errores:

```
2021-01-15 13:05:35,411 10144 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0-20200401 
2021-01-15 13:05:35,411 10144 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\setup\odoo.conf 
2021-01-15 13:05:35,411 10144 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['c:\\users\\usuario\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\12.0', 'c:\\odoosrc\\odo_dev_12\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\odoosrc\\odoo_dev_12\\odoo\\addons', 'C:\\odoosrc\\odoo_dev_12\\odoo\\addons'] 
2021-01-15 13:05:35,411 10144 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@localhost:5432 
2021-01-15 13:05:35,627 10144 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2021-01-15 13:05:36,675 10144 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on CHRISTIAN-PC1:8069 
2021-01-15 13:06:06,404 10144 INFO ? odoo.http: Generating nondb routing 
2021-01-15 13:06:06,574 10144 INFO None odoo.service.db: Create database `ut4`. 
2021-01-15 13:06:08,366 10144 ERROR None odoo.service.db: CREATE DATABASE failed: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\odoo\service\db.py", line 58, in _initialize_db
    odoo.modules.db.initialize(cr)
  File "C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\odoo\modules\db.py", line 34, in initialize
    for i in odoo.modules.get_modules():
  File "C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\odoo\modules\module.py", line 408, in get_modules
    plist.extend(listdir(ad))
  File "C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\odoo\modules\module.py", line 401, in listdir
    for it in os.listdir(dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'c:\\odoosrc\\odo_dev_12\\odoo\\addons'
2021-01-15 13:06:08,387 10144 ERROR None odoo.modules.loading: Database ut4 not initialized, you can force it with `-i base` 
2021-01-15 13:06:08,641 10144 INFO ut4 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2021 13:06:08] "POST /web/database/create HTTP/1.1" 200 - 13 1.673 0.614
2021-01-15 13:06:35,858 10144 ERROR ut4 odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'
ERROR: no existe la relación «ir_module_module»
LINE 1: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base...
```

Me he fijado que uno de los errores dice:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'c:\\odoosrc\\odo_dev_12\\odoo\\addons'
```

Y no entiendo porqué me muestra las rutas con doble barra en vez de con una sola barra. ¿Qué tendría que hacer? Me parece que está ahí el error y por eso no me puede crear la base de datos, pero no consigo solucionarlo y que la ruta correcta aparezca con tan solo una barra.

Paso también mi archivo de configuración de Odoo (odoo.conf) por si es útil.

```
[options]
admin_passwd = (contraseña)
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = (usuario)
db_password = (contraseña)
db_name = False
dbfilter = odoo12
log_db = False
log_db_level = warnings
log_handler = :INFO
addons_path = c:\odoosrc\odo_dev_12\odoo\addons
list_db = True
log_level = info
#logfile = C:\odoosrc\odoo_dev_12\setup\odoo.log
```

¡Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras mucha investigación respondo a mi propia pregunta. He cambiado la línea donde dice "addons_path" en el fichero "odoo.conf". El valor de este parámetro "addons_path" lo he cambiado de ruta absoluta a ruta relativa (pues la ruta absoluta estaba mal escrita). Ese error aparece cuando, entre otras cosas, hay un problema con la ruta para acceder a los módulos. Entonces, me ha funcionado. Lo he dejado e la siguiente forma:

```
addons_path = ..\odoo\addons,..\mismodulos
```

Lo dejo documentado para que alguien con el mismo problema le sirva.